# Calculate the shortest decimal number that is approximated by a given float

Tags: python, floating-point

The python floating point docs (eg https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) state

> Interestingly, there are many different decimal numbers that share the same nearest approximate binary fraction. For example, the numbers `0.1` and `0.10000000000000001` and `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` are all approximated by `3602879701896397 / 2 ** 55`. Since all of these decimal values share the same approximation, any one of them could be displayed while still preserving the invariant eval(repr(x)) == x.
>
> Historically, the Python prompt and built-in `repr()` function would choose the one with 17 significant digits, `0.10000000000000001`. Starting with Python 3.1, Python (on most systems) is now able to choose the shortest of these and simply display `0.1`.

Is there a way I can get that shortest representation as a `decimal.Decimal` (or other exact representation)?

Obviously one way would be `decimal.Decimal(repr(0.1))` but I'm wondering if there is something explicit that doesn't rely on the vague "on most systems" caveat and possibly is available as a package that would work with earlier version of python.

(Also, functions that do this in other languages may be of interest if there is nothing in python, as this is really a general floating point question)

Comment: The algorithms for doing this well are fairly complicated and the subject of academic papers, such as [this one](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~lerner/papers/fp-printing-popl16.pdf). However, I suspect you want to use an existing routine or language feature. Python is loosely specified; it does not currently guarantee this behavior, as you note. JavaScript and Java do. Since you indicate using other languages may be an option, you could consider those. I believe it is the default formatting for floating-point in both of those.

Comment: Thanks for that tip - I'm interested in other languages as a means of tracking down an algorithm to use, so all of the ideas you mentioned have helped to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may be useful:

- Python provides `PyOS_double_to_string`, but [the code comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pystrtod.c#L795)  says this is only used if `_Py_dg_dtoa` is not available.
- `_Py_dg_dtoa` is available in [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/dtoa.c#L2243) but I'm not sure if it can be accessed publicly. (In particular, it would be nice if there was a way to 'prove' that a the python interpreter we are using is using this internally). This function has detailed documentation about the way the string conversion is done, and it explains which flags to use to get the shortest decimal representation. If this was available from the interpreter this might be the best option as using it directly would give certainty about what was happening.
- The implementation of Errol can be found on [git](https://github.com/marcandrysco/Errol/tree/master/lib) and the paper found [here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~lerner/papers/fp-printing-popl16.pdf) has references to many other implementations along with a summary of their pros and cons.

Any one of the float -> string methods mentioned above would be a reasonable way to proceed, as would the standard `repr` method but it will require digging into the implementation details to be sure that a particular method guarantees to give you what you a looking for.

Comment: thanks @eric-postpischil for pointing out the Errol paper!  (I'd have mentioned you in the answer but apparently it isn't considered good SO style to do that).